# Old School RuneScape: Interaction between pickaxe speed bonus and capped XP rates?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

[2007wiki](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Motherlode_Mine#Rates) provides the following comparison of Oldschool RuneScape Mining experience rates for iron powermining at various levels, assuming a dragon pickaxe is used:

```
Level | Iron exp/h (dragon pickaxe)
61      49,350
75      52,290
85      52,290
99      52,290
```

2007wiki mentions that a dragon pick is "15% faster" than a rune pick.

**In the case of iron ore, where the XP rate hits a cap at a certain level, does the dragon pickaxe's 15% advantage affect:**

- ***A*: the *value* of the capped exp rate, or**
- ***B*: just the *level* at which one reaches this rate?**

If **A** is true, the exp per hour vs level relationship for mining iron with rune pickaxe would look something like:

```
Level | Dragon exp/h | Rune exp/h
61      49,350         42,900
75      52,290         45,400
85      52,290         45,400
99      52,290         45,400
```

with dragon pickaxe exp rates always 15% higher than rune.

If **B** is true, the exp-level relationship for rune pickaxe would instead be something like:

```
Level | Dragon exp/h | Rune exp/h
61      49,350         42,900
75      52,290         45,400
85      52,290         48,000
99      52,290         52,290
```

with dragon pickaxe exp rates 15% higher until reaching a cap, then rune gradually catching up to the cap.

Comment: You don't have to add 'Oldschool RuneScape' to the start of every question. That's what we have tags for

Comment: @PrivatePansy [This interesting Meta.SE topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) partially discusses this; it's certainly not necessary, but most discussants in the linked question seem to think it's at worst harmlessly redundant and at best useful

Answer (score 1):

Yes mining would be slower with a rune pick opposed to dragon.

Every pickaxe level comes with a 15% efficiency increase. So by using a rune pickaxe you will be mining at a constant rate 15% lower than if you were to mine with a dragon pickaxe. This would effect your experience rate drastically over a long period of time.

Comment: So mining iron until 85 should be the best way to train. After 85 it's most efficient to mine granite to 99.

Comment: So the exp rate from iron would cap out at 52290/1.15 = 45.5K per hour with a rune pickaxe, even at level 99?