# What is the mining formula, or average rates?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I want to know how many ore/hr I can mine, given:

- Pickaxe material
- Mining level
- Ore being mined

(Which are, as far as I know, the only 3 factors)

Now, I don't think the formula for this is available, at least checking the [OSRS Wiki on Mining](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Mining). I am almost positive whatever it is a % chance to mine the ore per tick of game time, but that's about it. There may be a brief pause between when the ore is clicked and when the rolls start, but I'm not sure how long it is and how much is just delay from going to and from the server.

There was [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248103/old-school-runescape-interaction-between-pickaxe-speed-bonus-and-capped-xp-rate) on the topic, but I think it is no longer valid, as the wiki stripped out the part it mentioned, I think due to lack of source.

However, if there was a large body of empirical data, I could also work with that.

Has anyone gathered a large body of data on this? I've seen little snippets of data given a dragon pick and a specific level, but that isn't very useful.

I think if there was enough data, a formula could be reverse-engineered, but is there something I'm missing?